# Bootstrap CSS: override breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, breakpoints

I'm trying to set the `sm` breakpoint so that it is `>=500` as opposed to the default of `576`

I don't use Sass or anything along those lines, so have just been trying to make the change directly into the CSS (I really miss the customiser that Boostrap 3 had)

I of course don't want to tamper with the Boostrap CSS file, but did see the breakpoint values in there. And so I added the following in the `<head>` section of my HTML

```
<style>
    :root{
        --breakpoint-xs:0;
        --breakpoint-sm:500px;
        --breakpoint-md:768px;
        --breakpoint-lg:992px;
        --breakpoint-xl:1200px
</style>
```

But it doesn't appear to be working, as I'm viewing it at 568px and not seeing any changes I've made

Comment: is your `<style>` section placed after the bootstrap.css?

Comment: @AkberIqbal yep have made sure of that — even tried adding an `!important` in there — it just seems to be sticking to the default breakpoint of `≥576px`. In fact, I've even checked in the Chrome inspector and, according to that, my styles are overwriting the default ones, but doesn't appear that way when I view the page itself!

Comment: If you add a minimal code which reproduces this behavior, it’ll be easy to help